# Automapper always showing children entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-5

I have a parent class: Item.
And a related, child class: Position.

I don't want to include Item as child of the Position class.
But when I use automapper, Item is always included as child of Position.

Classes:

```
// Item
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set;}


// Position
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public int CoordinateX { get; set; }
  public int CoordinateY { get; set; }
  public Item Item { get; set; }


// Item DTO
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }

// Mapping profile
   CreateMap<Item, ItemDTO>();
```

I get an Item like so:

```
Item item = dbContext.Items.AsNoTracking().Include(p => p.Positions);
```

It **correctly** returns the result. This is what I expect to see. Something like:

```
{
  Id: 1
  Name: "ABC",
  Positions:
    [
      {
        Id: 1,
        ItemId: 1,
        CoordinateX: 10,
        CoordinateY: 15,
        Item: []
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        ItemId: 1,
        CoordinateX: 13,
        CoordinateY: 18,
        Item: []
      }
    ]
}
```

Note that the Item object in the children records is empty.
However, if I use automapper, Item is always included as child of Position.

```
var result = mapper.Map<ItemDTO>(item);
```

It produces the following result:

```
{
  Id: 1
  Name: "ABC",
  Positions:
    [
      {
        Id: 1,
        ItemId: 1,
        CoordinateX: 10,
        CoordinateY: 15,
        Item:
        [
          Id: 1,
          Name: "ABC",
          Positions: []
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        ItemId: 1,
        CoordinateX: 13,
        CoordinateY: 18,
        Item:
        [
          Id: 1,
          Name: "ABC",
          Positions: []
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I use automapper and still achieve the expected result?
I'm using .NET 5 and automapper 8.1.1
I tried using the .Ignore property in the mapping profile, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're not "mapping" the `Position` list, you're copying the reference.

I would create a `PositionDTO` as well, and configure the mapping from `Position` to `PositionDTO` to ignore the `Item` property. Otherwise you're still carrying references to the raw data object in your DTO, which is defeating the purpose of the DTO.